# null http response in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i am developing a mobile application with flutter and laravel at the back end, i made an api to add new record, and when i test the api with Thunder client, it worked perfectly, but when i call it from flutter i got null response.

[this is how the error looks lik](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6X14.png)

```
final _messengerState = scaffoldKey.currentState; // this variable is for the snackbar
scanParticipant() async {
    Map data = {
      'event': 1,
      'participant': 11,
      'recorder': 6,
    };
    print(data);

    Response response = await _crud.postRequest(addParticipantRoute, data);
    ...
  }
```

```
postRequest(String url, Map data) async {
    try {
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}, body: data);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error catch $e');
    }
  }
```

and the backend

```
public function addRecord(Request $request)
    {

        $fields = $request->validate([
            'event' => 'required|integer',
            'participant' => 'required|integer',
            'recorder' => 'required|integer'
        ]);

        $user = Record::where('event',$fields['event'])->where('participant',$fields['participant'])->first();
        
        if($user == null) 
        {
            Record::create([
                'event' => $fields['event'],
                'participant' => $fields['participant'],
                'recorder' => $fields['recorder'],
                'moment' => Carbon::now()->addHour(),
            ]);

            return response([
                'message' => 'success',
            ],201);
        }else {
            return response([
                'message' => 'already scanned'
            ],422);
        }
        
    }
```

note : i login before trying this function

Comment: If `postResponse` catches an exception, it won't return anything (and implicitly returns `null`).  What is the error message that the `catch` block printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem later.
The problem was in the data variable,
I should turn all the fields into string then send it.

```
Map data = {
  'event': '1',
  'participant': '11',
  'recorder': '6',
};
```